# Is it possible to jump Dialogflow followup intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I create 2 custom follow up intent and for this 2 custom follow up intent there is 3 more follow up intent. Everything is fine. I take information from this 2 stage and then show the result. The process is about 2 follow up question and then finally a text response. But when the user gives the 1 or 2 information in his/her question then how can I bypass my follow up question and show them the results directly without asking the question.
Please see this photo for better understanding and please help me with this issue.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1):

Your use case does not require any extra follow-up intents at all, you can achive this only using single intent and 2 entities.

- Make an intent
- Give sample utterances for all the use cases
- Define two entities for for course-elective and course-degree
- Mark them as required
- Define prompts for them in case they are not provided by user

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: First time I did this but how could I implement the use case like if someone wants to know about 130 credit and another wants to know about 134 credit and there are 3 more section in each for degree program(cse,eee,ete). I can't provide same info for all case.It will different for each case.

Comment: @NazmusShakib that will be done using `fulfillment webhooks`, in your code use simple `if-else` or `switch` statements.

Comment: Is there anyway without webhooks to do it because I don't have an API to connect or collect data.